# How to sort a GridView by clicking on the header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to sort a GridView by clicking on the header. I guess all i need is the header name and then pass it into sql to get the data back sorted. How is it possible to get the header name?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a standard ASP.NET `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView`, you can simply "Enable Sorting", in the properties pane by setting "AllowSorting" to **true** or via the "pop-out" on the top right of the control by checking "Enable Sorting"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Matt Berseth suggest one of the best solution for sorting by header [here](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/09/how_to_improve_column_sort_pre.html)